# Set my refresh rate too high by accident with the AMD Catalyst taskbar icon. Can't see what I'm doing

Tags: windows-8, resolution, amd-catalyst, refresh-rate

And booting in safe mode doesn't help, as you can't uninstall catalyst (it says windows installer service not running or something) or change the desktop resolution/refresh.

Anyone know how to change my Catalyst desktop refresh rate or resolution from config files or registry or something?

Any other ideas?

Comment: I would just disable the service itself which will prevent from starting you can do this in safe mode.

Comment: I didn't disable the service, but I did disable all the catalyst stuff in the startup menu, and it didn't help. Maybe once the desktop is already set at that resolution/rate, it stays that way after restarts even without catalyst running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will want to access the [Advanced Startup Options](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/windows-startup-settings-including-safe-mode), and then follow the instructions to Enable Low-resolution Video (640x480).  Once it starts at that resolution, it essentially temporarily resets your current video resolution and refresh settings to a basic default.  You can from there, set your resolution and refresh to what you want, and restart.

So, it's not as much a matter of booting to safe mode, but still following almost the same path to boot to safe mode.

> - Under Advanced startup, tap or click Restart now.
> - On the Choose an option screen, tap or click Troubleshoot.
> - Tap or click Startup Settings.
> - Tap or click Restart.
> - On the Startup Settings screen, choose the startup setting you want.

That startup setting, would be Enable low-resolution video (640x480)

Comment: Thanks! This worked eventually; I had to boot using a win 8 DVD to get into safe mode (NOT straightforward), then use msconfig to turn safe mode off, but not restart yet, then "hold shift - click Power Off - Restart" to get into a version of Adv Start Ops that had the Startup Settings option. Then I chose Low Res from the boot menu, but it went into safe mode again. But using msconfig to get out of safe mode and shift-restart trick 3 times it finally "stuck" and started in low res mode. Anyway, I'll accept this answer in a few days unless someone knows a else knows a better fix. Thanks again.